Parallelization with joblib does not improve performance
Trying to get into parallelization for the first time. Came across joblib and parallel. Just trying the user manual's example and there's no improvement in performance when using the code - quite the opposite. I must be missing something obvious? I don't see what that is.
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time

i_range = 1000000

start = time.time()
[sqrt(i ** 2) for i in range(i_range)]
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed time = %s" % (end - start)) # Elapsed time = 0.48667478561401367

start = time.time()
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(i_range))
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed time = %s" % (end - start)) # Elapsed time = 12.57265043258667


You create 1_000_000 tasks to be scheduled independently and each task last for only dozens of µs which is rather very small. Scheduling a task, doing function calls from CPython and picking/unpicking data to be sent to other processes is far more expensive than computing a sqrt.

You should create 1000~10000 less tasks and use a loop inside your function to iterate over chunks of items. Pickling/Unpickling/Inter-process-communications are still expensive but this is a fundamental limitation of CPython (especially multiprocessing, but multithreading is often useless for computations due to the GIL). You need to use more expensive functions so for the data transfer overhead not to be significant compare to the computation time.

Put it shortly, CPython parallelism sucks. For such kind of computation, you should use vectorization instead. Objects are inherently slow due to the interpreted and objects themselves. Numpy can do that far more efficiently (faster and using less memory). Numexpr can do the same thing than Numpy here and in parallel (without the limitation of CPython regarding parallelism because it uses its own internal threads and they are not limited by the GIL).
